# Google Tag Manager logic/rule to fire only one ad tracking impression tag per session

Tags: session, google-tag-manager

Does anyone have a strong logic statement or macro that would limit the number of DFA impressions pixels that fire for a session on URL?

Use case: I show up at site.com, logic fires ad tracking tag based on referrer, I then go back to a different site and within a 30 minute session length, come back to site.com but new referrer means new ad tracking tag fires.

Is there logic to say only fire first ad tracking tag as fist ad tracking tag should be attributed?

Answer (score 1):

Not natively, no. You can set a cookie with the same event as your tracking tag. Then you can set up a blocking rule that checks for the existence of this (1st party) cookie and prevents the tag from firing if it's there (at least that's what I use and it works reasonably well).